# Find first integral ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given a system of ODE's and after a variable change indicated in the formulation I reach this:
$$\begin{cases} x^\prime = x^3(u-3) \\ u^\prime = x^2(1-u^2)\end{cases}\;. $$
Now I want to find a first integral (let's call it $E$) that fits this equation:
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial x}x^3(u-3)+\frac{\partial E}{\partial u}x^2(1-u^2)=0$$
But I don't know how to solve this. Could someone please help?

Comment: The question is not clear enough. What means $u'$ and $x'$ (derivative wrt. which variable ?). They are four symbols in the wording of the question : $x,y,u,E$. What among them are functions ? and functions of what variables ?

Comment: You should add the original system and the change of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote :
$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial x}x^3(u-3)+\frac{\partial E}{\partial y}x^2(1-u^2)=0$$
The symbols of variables seems not consistent. I suppose that there is a typo and that the PDE is :
$$\frac{\partial E(x,u)}{\partial x}x^3(u-3)+\frac{\partial E(x,u)}{\partial u}x^2(1-u^2)=0$$
May be it is $y$ instead of $u$. If so, change all the respective symbols in the calculus below.

Also I suppose that your system of two ODEs comes from the associated Charpit-Lagrange system of characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{x^3(u-3)}=\frac{du}{x^2(1-u^2)}=\frac{dE}{0}=dt$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $dE=0\quad\implies\quad E=c_1$

A second chatacteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{x^3(u-3)}=\frac{du}{x^2(1-u^2)}\quad\implies\quad \frac{1}{x}dx=\frac{u-3}{1-u^2}du$

$\ln|x|=\int \frac{u-3}{1-u^2}du=\ln\left|\frac{u-1}{(u+1)^2}\right|+$constant.

$$\frac{(u-1)}{x(u+1)^2}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE is $c_1=F(c_2)$ :
$$E(x,u)=F\left(\frac{(u-1)}{x(u+1)^2}\right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to some boundary condition (not specified in the wording of the question).

Answer (score 1):

$$\left\{ \begin{array}[c] xx'=x^3(u-3) \\ u'=x^2(1-u^2)\end{array}\right \}$$
I suupose that $u'=\dfrac {du}{dt}$:
$$\dfrac {dx}{du}=\dfrac {x(u-3)}{1-u^2}$$
It's separable.